# simplify an existing query (with clause with subselect from dual)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some querys like the following and want to simplify these querys.
Is there a shorter way to get the same result. 
I want to do it without the `with clause` and without the use of `dual` table, if possible.
Maybe with analytical functions.

```
with tab1 as
( select 
    DEPARTMENT1,DEPARTMENT2,DEPARTMENT3,DEPARTMENT4,DEPARTMENT5,DEPARTMENT6,DEPARTMENT7,DEPARTMENT8 
 from 
    RECLAMATION 
 where 
   RECLAMATIONDATE between to_Date('20150101','YYYYMMDD') and to_Date('20151231','YYYYMMDD')
)
select 
   (select count(*) from tab1 ) sumAll, 
   (select count(*) from tab1 where DEPARTMENT1=1) sum1, 
   (select count(*) from tab1 where DEPARTMENT2=1) sum2, 
   (select count(*) from tab1 where DEPARTMENT3=1) sum3, 
   (select count(*) from tab1 where DEPARTMENT4=1) sum4, 
   (select count(*) from tab1 where DEPARTMENT5=1) sum5, 
   (select count(*) from tab1 where DEPARTMENT6=1) sum6, 
   (select count(*) from tab1 where DEPARTMENT7=1) sum7, 
   (select count(*) from tab1 where DEPARTMENT8=1) sum8
from dual;
```

> there are 8 department columns. Each contains the value 1 if the department is involved in an reclamation and 0 when not.

The result looks like:

```
sumAll | sum1 | sum2 | sum3 | sum4 | sum5 | sum6 | sum7 | sum8
-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----
   100 |   14 |   71 |   53 |   18 |    0 |   19 |   17 |   88
```

The tablestructure is given, and it'n not an option to redesign it.

Comment: Seems like a poor table design. Do you really have 8 different department columns?!?

Comment: yes, there are 8 department columns. Each contains the value 1 if the department is involved in an reclamation and 0  when not.

Comment: the tablestructure is given, and i have to do the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there are 8 department columns. Each contains the value 1 if the department is involved in an reclamation and 0 when not.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS SumAll,
       SUM( DEPARTMENT1 ) AS Sum1,
       SUM( DEPARTMENT2 ) AS Sum2,
       SUM( DEPARTMENT3 ) AS Sum3,
       SUM( DEPARTMENT4 ) AS Sum4,
       SUM( DEPARTMENT5 ) AS Sum5,
       SUM( DEPARTMENT6 ) AS Sum6,
       SUM( DEPARTMENT7 ) AS Sum7,
       SUM( DEPARTMENT8 ) AS Sum8
FROM   RECLAMATION
WHERE  EXTRACT( YEAR FROM RECLAMATIONDATE ) = 2015
```

Note, I've uses `EXTRACT` to filter the date as using `BETWEEN` you will get the dates up to and including `2015-12-31T00:00:00` but it will ignore dates between `2015-12-31T00:00:01` and `2015-12-31T23:59:59` (which I'm assuming is not what you require).

Comment: Thanks, thats much simpler. In these case the time is always 00:00:00, so between works. But i will notice your tip with extract year for the future.

Comment: If you want to use between then you can always use ANSI Date literals to simplify things: `WHERE RECLAMATIONDATE BETWEEN DATE '2015-01-01' AND DATE '2015-12-31'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
select count(*),
       sum(case when DEPARTMENT1=1 then 1 else 0 end) as dep1,
       ...
       sum(case when DEPARTMENT8=1 then 1 else 0 end) as dep8
 from 
    RECLAMATION 
 where 
   RECLAMATIONDATE between to_Date('20150101','YYYYMMDD') and to_Date('20151231','YYYYMMDD')
```